# Creating a random number simulation in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

myam new to Java, and My teacher asked me to make a program that prints random numbers. First it is supposed to ask the user what the maximum number is and then it is supposed to print numbers in that range. This was the code I was given, and I am very confused how to use it. If someone knows how to do this please help, thank you.

```
public class RandomNmbers {
public static void main(String [] args){
        EasyReader console = new EasyReader();
        System.out.println ("What is the maximum number?");
        { int maxRandomNum = console.readInt();
    String RandomNum = null;
System.out.println ("The random number is" + RandomNum);
        }
}

         public static int getRandomNumber(int max) 
{int num = (int) (Math.random() * max) + 1; return num;}
int count = 1;
private int numToPrint; 
}
```

Comment: Hey just a heads up, this is not Javascript. It is Java. It is kind of confusing for people new to programming, but they are actually not related except for name. That being said, I think there is a green play button in the interface that should compile and then run the code for you.

Comment: why can't you ask "code giver" how to use it?

Comment: @AlexBieg I cant seem to find a green play button, where would it be?

Comment: @AmberLove I don't use NetBeans personally, but [this](https://netbeans.org/images_www/v6/8/screenshots/java-editor.png) is what the interface looks like. At the top there is a green arrow. I think that will run the program.

Comment: I encourage you to fix the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomNumbers {
    //int count = 1;
private static int numToPrint; 
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("What is the maximum number?");
        int maxRandomNum = sc.nextInt();
        String RandomNum = Integer.toString(RandomNumbers.getRandomNumber(maxRandomNum));
        numToPrint=Integer.parseInt(RandomNum);
        System.out.println ("The random number is" + RandomNum);

}
    public static int getRandomNumber(int max) 
    {
        int num = (int) (Math.random() * max) + 1; 
        return num;
    }
}
```

This code should work, Switched EasyReader with scanner though else pretty much your code, there were just a few things missing.